Manga where a kind old man reincarnates as a white-haired prince
I am looking for a manga with a male main character who is kind old man and reincarnates as an op white haired prince.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you remember anything else about this?  Reincarnating as an OP character is pretty much de rigueur these days, so every little bit helps.  When and where did you read this?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?
